# Check Out / Check In System for Floating Licenses

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to manage multiple floating licenses (e.g. Oracle Database) from a master configuration server using a pull model. Normally I use Puppet to handle configuration stuff like this, but I'm having trouble finding any info on managing floating licenses with Puppet.

Any suggestions on how I do this?

For example, I have 5 unique Oracle Licenses kept in separate files and I need some way for systems to be able to check in or check out those licenses. Each license can't be used by more than one system at a time. Also I need to send an e-mail if a system tries to check out a license but there are none left.

Normally I'd be trying to just figure out how to do this with Puppet, but I'm realizing this is going beyond my familiarity with Ops in general

Comment: Manage the licenses with symlinks.